# flutter check stream for new items

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

***TL;DR at the end***

I am building an app to read data from color measuring devices via bluetooth.

Maybe, in the future, the app wil replace the very expensive OLED displays, and measurements will only be triggered from the app. However, now, in the transitioning phase, measurements can be triggered both from the app and the colorimeter. This raises the problem of getting the data on the device running the app, no matter where the measurement is triggered. The bluetooth input is handled as a stream.

How can i run a small service in the background that checks the stream for a new (specific) input without discarding other inputs? And would this cost less battery than polling the colorimeter like once every two seconds?

***TL;DR:***

1. How do I constantly check a Stream for new items, while reomving only items from the stream that fit certain conditions?
2. How do I implement such a solution into my app?
3. Is this more battery efficient than polling the device status every two seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Since your data comes via a Stream you should take a look at `StreamBuilder` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html Here you can find a video on it and some example code fo you to use.